# How to sort elements in a column in v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-data-table and the elements in the first columns are some true and false values. By clicking the 'sortable' icon in the header I sort these elements in the column. I want to make that when I open the page, the 'true' values to be sorted first. How can I manage this?

```
   headers: [
  {
    text: '',
    sortable: true,
    value: 'status',
  }]
```

Html:

```
<v-data-table
:pagination.sync="pagination"
:headers="headers"
:items="items"
>
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <v-icon v-if="status">
         {{status}}
      </v-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </template>
 </v-data-table>
```

Values of status are like: True, False, True, False, False

I want to sort the elements of the column as that: True True False False False

Firstly true values and than false.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort-by` and `sort-desc`

```
<v-data-table
  :pagination.sync="pagination"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  sort-by="status"
  :sort-desc="true"
>
<template>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <v-icon v-if="status">
         {{status}}
      </v-icon>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </template>
 </v-data-table>
```

You can check more [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#props)

Answer (score 0):

You can use external sorting using `sortBy` and `sortDesc`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    headers: [ { text: '', sortable: true, value: 'status' } ],
    items: [ { status: "True" }, { status: "False" }, { status: "True" } ],
    sortBy: "status",
    sortDesc: true
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<v-app id="app">
  <v-data-table 
    :headers="headers" 
    :items="items"
    :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
    :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
  >
    <template v-slot:item.status="{ item }">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <v-icon v-if="item.status">{{item.status}}</v-icon>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</v-app>
```

Comment: They didnt work, I have tried something with :custom-sort="customSort"

Comment: customSort(items) {
      return items.sort().reverse();
    },

Comment: But doesnt work either

Comment: @Nina if you run the above demo, `True` will be listed first then `False`. Is this different from the output you were expecting?